# PHP: Combine array of arrays and get lowest value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 26
    [1] => 644
)
Array
(
    [0] => 20
    [1] => 26
    [2] => 644
)
Array
(
    [0] => 26
)
Array
(
    [0] => 47
)
Array
(
    [0] => 47
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 18
)
Array
(
    [0] => 26
    [1] => 18
)
Array
(
    [0] => 26
    [1] => 644
    [2] => 24
    [3] => 181
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 41
    [7] => 31
)
Array
(
    [0] => 26
    [1] => 644
    [2] => 24
    [3] => 181
    [4] => 12
    [5] => 25
    [6] => 41
    [7] => 31
)
Array
(
    [0] => 181
)
Array
(
    [0] => 181
)
Array
(
    [0] => 899
)
```

I need to join all of these arrays into one array, so that I can get the lowest number (in this case it would be 3). I tried to use join($array), however that return only a string with which I cannot determine the lowest number. And min($array) just returns the lowest number of each array.
I'm not sure what the right term would be for what I'm looking for so I'm hoping someone can help me.

Comment: Use array_merge and find min on that final array

Example: 
$a1=array("red","green");
$a2=array("blue","yellow");
print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));

Comment: For your future questions, please use `var_export()` instead of `var_dump()`, so we can copy/paste the array for tests

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple one:

```
$array = [[26, 18], [3], [47, 3], [4, 47, 18], [20, 26, 644]];
echo min(array_merge(...$array));
```

Splat operator `...` makes all your subarrays as **arguments** to `array_merge`, which in turn merges all subarrays into **one**, and standard php function `min` finds the minimum element in this array.

Comment: this returns: 26202647318612186186899

Comment: Oh, it seemed my PHP version was not up to date

Answer (score 1):

Transform the initial array by applying the min function to each sub-array.  You'll then have an array of minimum values.  You can then apply the min function to the whole array to find the minimum of minimums:

```
<?php
$min_ar = array_map('min', $array);
echo min($min_ar)
```